# Django data passing with a tag or href

Tags: python, django

I have a table that contains a link and I would like to pass some data to my a function when the link is clicked for more actions.

```
***my.html***

<table>
 <tbody>
 {% for query in queries %}
  <tr>
   <td name="my_data" value="{{query.name}}"><a href="/internal/my_func">{{query.name}}</a>
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my url

```
***urls.py***

from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from app.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^internal/my_func$', my_func),
)
```

my views

```
***views.py***

def my_func(request):
 # how do i get the query.name value here for me to perform more actions on it
 query = request.Get.get('my_data')

 # this does not work
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use query parameters in the link?  Like: `<a href="/internal/my_func?param1=value1&param2=value2">`?

Comment: No reason, I would try that now

Comment: Doesn't seems to work, is there another method of option?

Comment: What data are you trying to pass to your function?

Comment: query.name. The data I have in the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try using query parameters in the url string for your anchor tag:

```
<a href="/internal/my_func?query_name={{ query.name|urlencode }}">{{ query.name }}</a>
```

Then in your view file you can access it with:

```
def my_func(request):
    # Get query_name from request
    query = request.GET.get('query_name')
```

Note that I used `request.GET` instead of `request.Get`.