# Unable to pass data inside anchor tag to views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to build a document retrieval engine. On entering a query, the user gets a list of documents sorted by relevancy. But just getting the name of documents isn't very helpful. So instead of simply displaying the table, I hyperlinked the document name. Within the anchor tags is the name of the document. When a user clicks this link, I want to display the contents of this file to user using the document name. So basically, when a user clicks the link I want to pass the contents within the tags to my view function. Following are some parts of my code that are relevant.

the `.html` page

```
<table class = "tab_results">
    <tr>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
    {% for each_pair in results%}
    <tr> 
        <td name = 'project_name'><a id = 'doc_name' href = "doc_viewer/?query_name={{ each_pair.0|urlencode }}">{{ each_pair.0 }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ each_pair.1 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

my `urls.py` file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^index$', views.index),
    url(r'^[?]query=', views.doc_scorer, name="doc_scorer"),
    url(r'^doc_viewer[/]', views.doc_viewer, name="doc_viewer"),
]
```

Lastly the `views.py` file

```
def doc_viewer(request):
    project_name = request.GET.get('project_name')
    context = {'doc_data': search_query.doc_data(project_name)}
    return render_to_response('search/doc_viewer_temp.html', context)
```

I followed what was given here but I get the following error

```
TypeError at /search/doc_viewer/
cannot use label indexing with a null key
```

The issue is that the variable `project_name` is `NULL`. I tried the suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785477/django-data-passing-with-a-tag-or-href) link but cant make it work. Any idea where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: in urls.py use `r'^doc_viewer/$'`, in html you are using `query_name` as parameter, but in view trying to get `project_name`. These two should have same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For queries you can use `$` at the end of the url:

```
url(r'^doc_viewer/$', views.doc_viewer, name="doc_viewer"),
url(r'^$', views.index)
```

Also it is better to add index at the end (because ^$ can match most of the urls and make them broken).

Also query name should be same with `request.GET.get()` function's parameter, you used `query_name` in html and `project_name` in view function.